# Update function only running once

Tags: unity, c#

For some reason, the update function is only running once. Why does this happen?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LightFlicker : MonoBehaviour
{
    float timer;
    float timetowait;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        timer = 0;
        timetowait = Random.Range(0.01f, 0.8f);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Debug.Log("Updating");
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
        if(timer >= timetowait)
        {

            if (gameObject.activeInHierarchy == true)
            {
                gameObject.SetActive(false);
            }
            else
            {
               gameObject.SetActive(true);
            }
            timetowait = Random.Range(0.01f, 0.8f);
            timer = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The debug.log statement only fires 9 times. The timetowait changes, but the timer stays the same.

Comment: You deactivating your gameObject, so it stop updating.

Comment: @Woltus so instead of deactivating the gameobject, I deactivate the components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the gameobject is no longer active the code will no longer run in the update.
You can also simplify the flicker by removing the timer and stuff from the update and replace with a coroutine. Get a reference to the Light and call it like so.

```
Light _light;
void Start()
{
    _light = GetComponent<Light>();
    StartCoroutine("Flicker");
}
IEnumerator Flicker()
{
    while (true)
    {
        _light.enabled = _light.enabled ? false : true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(0.01f, 0.9f));
    }
}
```

Another option would be to set the light up with a flickering animation loop that you can set whenever needed

Answer (score 3):

When `timer >= timetowait` is `true`, since the game object IS active, you disable it with `SetActive(false)`. And from this point on, `Update` will never be executed, so you need to re-activate the game object from somewhere else. Or change your code based on what you want to accomplish.