# Why the update function only call once

Tags: unity, c#

I asked about this question [How to efficiently implement a 7-segment display?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/188356/how-to-efficiently-implement-a-7-segment-display/188358#188358) in previous post. Now I just add an update function to the last part of the code to display the time(I don't bother the exact time at the moment just want to make sure the number change regularly). However,I'm not sure why the update only run once, I checked the answer in this website, mentioned the root cause is gameobject deactivated([Update function only running once](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/142910/update-function-only-running-once)) but this is not my case. I tried with `void OnMouseDown(){Display(DateTime.Now.Second)}`, the number does change according to my mouse button so I'm not sure what wrong with Update function. In addition, I assigned all the variable but it still pop out message unassigned reference exception, not sure where the problem.

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

public class ClockDigit : MonoBehaviour
{
//  Assuming you number your segments as follows:
//   -- 0 --
//  |       |
//  5       1
//  |       |
//   -- 6 --
//  |       |
//  4       2
//  |       |
//   -- 3 --
// Store a lookup table for which segments 
// should be active when displaying each digit.
static readonly bool[,] SEGMENT_IS_ACTIVE = new bool[,] {

    {true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  false}, // 0
    {false, true,  true,  false, false, false, false}, // 1
    {true,  true,  false, true,  true,  false, true }, // 2
    {true,  true,  true,  true,  false, false, true }, // 3
    {false, true,  true,  false, false, true,  true }, // 4
    {true,  false, true,  true,  false, true,  true }, // 5
    {true,  false, true,  true,  true,  true,  true }, // 6
    {true,  true,  true,  false, false, false, false}, // 7
    {true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true,  true }, // 8
    {true,  true,  true,  true,  false, true,  true }  // 9
};

public Color32 activeColour = Color.red;
public Color32 inactiveColour = Color.black;
public SpriteRenderer[] segments = new SpriteRenderer[7];    

public void Display(int number)
{
    var digit = number % 10;
    if (digit < 0) digit *= -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        if (SEGMENT_IS_ACTIVE[digit, i])
        {
            segments[i].color = activeColour;
        }
        else
        {
            segments[i].color = inactiveColour;
        }
    }
}

public void Update()
{
    Display(DateTime.Now.Second);
           
}
}
```

I tried this command also, the infinite loop freeze the Unity and FixedUpdate() command also update the frame only one time.

```
void Update()
    {while(true)
      Display(DateTime.Now.Second);
    }
```

[image]

Comment: See the red error message at the bottom of your screen? You have an unassigned reference exception. Looks like you forgot to assign some of your references in the Inspector. I'm surprised to see this script on one of the individual rectangles though — you don't have 7 copies of this script in your scene, one on every segment, do you? You only need one copy for it to do its job.

Comment: The script itself runs without error. Make an empty gameobject for your counter that just contains the script and remove all other attached scripts of ClockDigit

Comment: Yeah I understood what the error suppose to mean but I don't spot any more reference I can assign in inspector. The is the part I confuse, I created 7 object(through"create empty") in unity, assign the script to one of the rectangle(Rect1) only, and from the script,assign the 7 spriterenderer to respective gameobject. If this is not correct, then how is it done?

Comment: I tested out your code using the steps you gave above and it's working fine for me. Try commenting out the call to `Display(DateTime.Now.Second);` in `Update()` and put a line in to print out to the console like 'Debug.Log("Running Update");` which will hopefully show that Update is running more than once.

Comment: Just click on the red message in your editor and it will tell you where else you placed your script since it brings you to the error message

Comment: Thanks everyone, I solved it already. I made a very silly mistake:) accidently added the script to main camera and not aware of it. In this condition, the error appear and the Update stopped, so Update run only once. As Daisy suggestion, commenting the "Display(DateTime.Now.Second)" and check the result with Debug.Log , in this case it run indefinitely as no error encounter.

Comment: Time to close the question, then.

Comment: Do you mean just tick my own answer as accepted answer then it will "close"? I'm not sure why the system pop out message that I need to wait 10hours to do that.

Comment: @chuackt There's a minimum wait time for accepting your own answer to [give the community adequate time to answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75200/228147). [Accepting an answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) is different than [closing a question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem already. I made a silly mistake by accidently added the script to main camera. When the Update function run, it encountered problem and stopped, so it only run once. Commenting out the Display(DateTime.Now.Second)and replace with a debug log, the debug log run indefinitely as no error encountered. I remove the script from main camera and it working as intended.